# Creating a networking application that can work over internet connections

Tags: networking, network-programming, ip-address

I have a somewhat basic understanding of network programming (and networking concepts in general) from taking a networking course in university a few years ago.

I remember being able to create a simple chat application, where the chat server is used as a central directory aware of which clients are currently online, but once a client knows another client it wants to chat with, the actual messages between them don't need to go through the server. I remember we could only test this over a bunch of LAN machines.

This C# chat program also has several comments mentioning that the program does not work over the internet: http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial239_Csharp-Chat-Part-1---Building-the-Chat-Client.html

My question is why do these applications not work over the internet when "commercial" chat applications can. Surely, there is some way to make my computer accessible to the outer network even if its IP address is not valid outside the network of the ISP.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with the linked-to code. The server doesn't even bind to a local address, which means it will listen for connections on all ip-addresses on the computer. There is however a comment for in the server article where the user changed the `TcpListener` object creation to bind to a specific address, which means clients only can connect to that specific address.

In the original server design, with using `TcpListenet` with only a port number, there should be nothing preventing its use on an Internet connected computer, unless there is a firewall blocking access.

Answer (score 0):

Were you aware of [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net) and in particular the short chat example demonstrating the functionality [here](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/src/952f51c14671/ExamplesConsole/BasicSend.cs) (It's less than 15 lines of code)? This was written specifically for people writing server-client apps in c# and given most of the problems you might come across will already have been solved and it might save you some time. This library is completely plug & play and has no issues working over the internet (as long as you can setup the necessary port forwarding where necessary).

Generally if both of your targets are behind NAT (so no true external ip addresses) and you are unable to configure port forwarding you need to look at 'TCP / UDP hole punching', quite an advanced technique.